# $state.go in factory being recognized yet ignored

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

so I'm setting up a service that will check if the current user is logged in and if not send them to my login state. I cannot fathom why this is not working. The state is being recognized because if I intentionally try an invalid state, she throws an error.

Currently I get both $log results not state change.

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('user-module', [])
    .factory('UserService', ['$state', '$log', UserService]);

/* @ngInject */
function UserService($state, $log) {

    return {
        login: login
    };

    //////////////////

    function login() {
        $log.info('Login fired...');
        $state.go('authentication.login');
        $log.info('Meh...');
    }
}
})();
```

No other errors are being thrown. Any ideas why this is simply being ignored?

Comment: You don't need `@ngInject`, you're doing the DI annotation manually

Comment: Wrap your code $state.go inside $timeout. it should work then.